# delete multiple remote files with the FTP command

Tags: scripting, rm, ftp

Right now we have a script that uses the FTP  mget command to download all the files in a specific location.  After after verifying the files have successfully downloaded we run a ftp delete command to delete each file that was downloaded.  We noticed that each ftp delete is creating a new connection and I was wondering if it is possible to delete each file in one connection?  I have a .txt file with all the file names that need to be deleted, but the file type varies a great deal so  it would be nice to be able to target each file individually.

Comment: Your ftp client may have an `mdelete` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use `lftp` instead of the regular `ftp` client. With `lftp` you can use `mget -E /path/to/files` which will delete the source files after succesful transfer.

See http://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html for the manual.